# How to left align SubMenu Links

Tags: jquery, css, megamenu

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DTJQL/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function ($)
        {
            $('#mega-menu-1').dcMegaMenu({
                rowItems: '3',
                speed: 'fast',
                effect: 'slide'
            });
        });
```

Using megamenu js file.[Megamenu Link](http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-mega-drop-down-menu-plugin/getting-started/)
i m facing issue How to left align SubMenu Links(Product 1,Product 2,product 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text is left aligned, however the `ul` is padded.

```
#mega-menu-1 ul {
   padding: 0;
   margin: 0;
}
```

Should remove the padding.

Comment: Got it IE 7 wants margin 0

Comment: @Means you can't always expect immediate responses from people on this site. But yes for IE7 you need to set the margin to 0 to.

Comment: Danny i have one quetion

Comment: I have to speed up hover menu pop up

Comment: try `speed: {duration:0}`. The plugin calls the [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) method with what you pass as the speed.

Comment: @Means instead of `speed: 'fast'` do `speed: {duration:0}`

Comment: @Means it is faster when I do it. Perhaps you should open another question to see if you can get help from others.